# Spatial join of feature class on layer class with PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, spatial-join

I have three layers:

- One point layer consisting of residents
- One polygon layer with buffers of the first layer (one polygon for every point)
- Another point layer consisting of containers

I use QGIS 3.4.1

It is possible that multiple container points are within a buffer polygon. My goal is to select all container points within a certain buffer **with PyQGIS**. Hence, I want to know which containers are near a certain resident. I use the following code:

```
from osgeo import ogr

#Open datalayers
inw = r"SomePath"
afc = r"SomePath"
inw_buff = r"SomePath"

#set-up for residents
driver_inw = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
dataSource_inw = driver_inw.Open(inw,0)
layer_inw = dataSource_inw.GetLayer()
layerDef_inw = layer_inw.GetLayerDefn()

#set-up for containers
driver_afc = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
dataSource_afc = driver_afc.Open(afc,0)
layer_afc = dataSource_afc.GetLayer()
layerDef_afc = layer_afc.GetLayerDefn()

#set-up for buffers
driver_buff = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
dataSource_buff = driver_buff.Open(inw_buff,0)
layer_buff = dataSource_buff.GetLayer()
layerDef_buff = layer_buff.GetLayerDefn()

#some coordinates from the residents point layer
for f in layer_inw:
    coordx_inw = f[7]
    coordy_inw = f[8]
    ID_inw = f[9]
    break

#find the corresponding buffer polygon
for y in layer_buff:
    if y[9] == ID_inw:
        temp_buff = y

processing.run("native:selectbylocation", {'INPUT':afc,'PREDICATE':[6],'INTERSECT':temp_buff,'METHOD':0})
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
exec(code, self.locals)
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
File "<string>", line 77, in <module>
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 96, in run
return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 139, in runAlgorithm
raise QgsProcessingException(msg)
_core.QgsProcessingException: Niet mogelijk uit te voeren algoritme
Kon bronlaag voor INTERSECT niet laden: ongeldige waarde
```

Translated from Dutch to English it says that the value for INTERSECT is invalid. I looked it up and it does indeed not except a feature class. I tried to place the attributes of the temp_buff into a freshly made QgsVectorLayer, but so far no success.